# Why does std::equality_comparable not work for std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector, c++20, c++-concepts

https://godbolt.org/z/P97MaK

I'm playing with concepts and expected std::is_equality_comparable to work for vector but it does not.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <concepts>


struct X {};

template<std::equality_comparable T>
bool foo( T v){
    return v == v;
}

int main()
{
    foo(10);
    foo(std::vector<X>{});
    
}
```

the compile error fails inside `foo` rather than at the function boundary protected by the concept.

[image]

Is this a bug or expected behaviour?

Comment: because `X` is not equality_comparable

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear. I know X is not equality comparable. However this also means that std::vector<X> is not equality comparable. I would expect it to fail there rather than inside the implementation of vector.

Comment: vector comparison operators are not SFINAE friendly, i.e. they are unconditionally defined, making `vector<X>` satisfying `equality_comparable` concept, even though you can't compare them.

Comment: The general question is what is the intended behaviour is std::is_equality_comparable for templated types. Is it intended to return true if it *might* be equality comparable.

Comment: For it to fail the vector's operators must be declared SFINAE friendly. That isn't currently required.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica  Is there an open request to make the operators in vector SFINAE friendly. It certainly is unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I haven't seen one yet. But I don't follow closely for a good while now. It would certainly make a lot of sense to conceptify the standard library's operator templates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A concepts only checks that the declaration is well formed, it doesn't check the definition.

The [comparison operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) for `std::vector` are not SFINAE friendly, i.e. they are unconditionally declared, meaning that `operator==(vector<T>, vector<T>)` always exists, even if `operator==(T, T)` doesn't exists. That's why `equality_comparable<std::vector<T>>` is always satisfied and you get an error on `v == v` inside the function.

For it to work properly the vector comparison operators should be constrained, i.e.:

```
template< class T, class Alloc >
    requires std::equality_comparable<T>
constexpr ret_type operator==( const std::vector<T,Alloc>& lhs,
                                       const std::vector<T,Alloc>& rhs );
```

Comment: For this to be fixed in the std::library does this require a change to the standard specification or is it undefined as to whether each vendor gcc/clang/msvc should/will fix it?

Comment: @bradgon the standard.  Note I write a custom trait that deals with this common case by testing the tyoe T instead of vector of T and falls back on the normal trait.